# Batch Size of Stateful LSTM in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

My Model is defined as below:

```
## defining the model
batch_size = 1

def my_model():

   
   input_x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 4), name='input')
   drop = Dropout(0.5)
   
   lstm_1 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 4), name='3dLSTM', stateful=True)(input_x)
   lstm_1_drop = drop(lstm_1)
   lstm_2 = LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 4), name='2dLSTM', stateful=True)(lstm_1_drop)
   lstm_2_drop = drop(lstm_2)

   y1 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='op1')(lstm_2_drop)
   y2 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='op2')(lstm_2_drop)
   
   model = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=[y1,y2])
   model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
   model.summary()
   return model

model = my_model()
```

It is a Stateful LSTM model with batch size =1. My `model.fit` looks like this :

```
# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    [y_11_train,y_22_train],
    epochs=1, 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    verbose=0, 
    shuffle=False)

model.reset_states()
```

My model runs well and outputs results. But I am unable to increase or alter the `batch_size` as flexibly as we could do when the model is in stateless condition.
As in for bigger size of dataset the model seems to be training forever as the `batch_size` here is just 1. And as we know we can't randomly put any `batch_size` value for `stateful LSTM` as it needs to be a divisible factor.

I have gone through some blogs which describes changing `batch_size` by using different batch sizes for training and predicting using the `get_weights()` and `set_weights()` functions in the Keras API ref: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/, still it seems to be that the `batch_size` that is being used here is less.

My question is : Cant we use batch size like 32, 64, 128 in stateful LSTMs? If yes then how do I implement it in my above given model, if not then what are the alternatives?

Looking for valuable suggestions.

**Post Edit**

In stateful LSTM `model.reset_states()` should be after every epoch, Hence I set the resetting of the states after each epoch in the following way:

```
for i in range(100):
    start = time.time()
    history = model.fit(x_train, [y_11_train,y_22_train], epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()

    print("Epoch",i, time.time()-start,"s")
```

Comment: I may be missing something but I believe you can just set batch size to None

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

I realized that I needed to find the `HCF` (highest common factor) of both the length of `x_train` and `x_test`. For this I wrote a simple `HCF` python code the output of it is the `batch_size`.

Hence data set of different size will have different batch sizes.

Following is the code I used to find the `HCF`:

```
def computeHCF(x, y):
    if x > y:
        smaller = y
    else:
        smaller = x
    for i in range(1, smaller+1):
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            hcf = i

    return hcf

batch_size= computeHCF(x_train.shape[0], x_test.shape[0])
```

And use this `batch_size`  both while defining the model, fitting the model(`model.fit(..)`) & predicting(`model.predict(...)`).

```
NOTE: We need to specify batch size while predicting the model. As:

model.predict(x_test, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 5):

The key part is, as you mentioned, batch size must be a value that divides without remainder into (I believe) the `train` and `validation` test set sizes.

One could find the highest common multiple (a.k.a. greatest common factor) of the dimensions of those two datasets, and that is your maximum batch size in a stateful LSTM. Check out this [simple explanation](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/number/factorsmultiplesrev2.shtml) if that is unclear.

You could try just a simple loop over something like:

```
for batch_size in range(128):
    try:
        model.train(...)
        print('Trained with batch size: {}'.format(batch_size))
    except:
        print('Couldn't use batch size: {}'.format(batch_size))
```

Just set #epochs to 1 and number of iterations to something small, or do whatever you can to reduce the time taken in each loop as you don't actually care about the results.

Comment: @n1k31t4- Thanks, I took the idea of HCF from your post and made an answer. :)

Comment: @n1k31t4 I dont understand why this should be the case. According to documentation, "stateful: If True, the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch.". So why should the size of the batch make a difference?

Comment: @DankMasterDan - if you use `batch_size=10` and have 101 samples, by default, Keras will send 10 batches of 10 samples and a final batch of 1 sample. That means a stateful layer will only receive 1 input at some point, when it is expecting 10. I suppose it should be possible to just ignore 9 indices, but it seems not to be implemented that way (or we are both missing some information!). There are [useful examples here](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/).